# Is ArgoUML still one of the popular UML modeling tools?

Tags: uml, tool-uml

I used Rational-Rose and StartUML in the past years.
  Sometime ago, I accepted a training about modeling, and noticed the tools is UML.
  Now, I tried to use it modeling my system, and find the help-document in the official-website is incomplete and the tool is not good as the website claimed. For example, the function undo/redo is not supported, and some issues are not updated for a long time.

Has [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) abandoned development for the next generation?

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of activity on the fora [ArgoUML forums](http://argouml-users.net/forum/) I'd voice your concerns and questions there.

Comment: It looks like the development has been to sleep since the end of 2011

Answer (score 0):

Not really, last release was in [December 2011](http://argouml.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectNewsList) and there's very little activity in their [SVN tracker](http://argouml.tigris.org/source/browse/argouml/).

Consider that they have yet to implement features as [Undo](http://argouml.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1834) and Redo, and you'll get an idea the general state of the project.

You may like to know that there's an actively maintained fork of the original StarUML code, it's [WhiteStarUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/).